# Using UUID's in rails forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-5, uuid

I'm starting to incorporate UUID's as a form of `id` obfuscation into my rails app. Upon creating a new record I have a form with hidden fields passing in the necessary ID's as values for the associated models, however, I'd like to pass the associated record's UUID as the value instead of the actual ID so that way the ID isn't hanging out in plain sight for anyone to inspect the HTML.

Standard rails form:

```
<%= form_for(@share_foo) do |f| %>
  ...
  <%= f.hidden_field :foo_id, value: @foo.uuid %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :foo_user_id, value: current_user.uuid %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Controller action:

```
def create
  ...
    @share_foo.foo_id = Foo.where(uuid: params[:share_foo][:foo_id]).pluck(:id).join("")
    @share_foo.foo_user_id = User.where(uuid: params[:share_foo][:foo_user_id]).pluck(:id).join("")
    if @share_foo.save
      flash.now[:success] = "Foo successfully shared to #{@share_foo.shared_to}!"
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = @share_foo.errors.full_messages.join(", ")
    end
  ...
end
```

I know that I can use the `to_params` method in my models to override rails to use `uuid` instead of `id` but I'm not at the point where I can change everything over to implement that for every model and foreign keys.

Is it okay to search and force values in my controller like that? Would it be better to have this code in the model somehow? (i.e. model callbacks/methods, etc.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to generate the uuid in the view? Create it in the controller like

```
def create
  ...
  @share_foo.id = uuid_generate_v4()
  @share_foo.foo_id = Foo.where(uuid: params[:share_foo][:foo_id]).pluck(:id).join("")
  @share_foo.foo_user_id = User.where(uuid: params[:share_foo][:foo_user_id]).pluck(:id).join("")
  if @share_foo.save
    flash.now[:success] = "Foo successfully shared to #{@share_foo.shared_to}!"
  else
    flash.now[:danger] = @share_foo.errors.full_messages.join(", ")
  end
end
```

Reminder: to use the uuid you need to put this in your `schema.rb`:

```
enable_extension "uuid-ossp"
```

Comment: Nono, all UUID's for each object are created in the model inside of a `:after_create` call back. I want to use an already generated UUID (of a user for example) to associate one record to another. Normally I pass values like that (i.e. a `:user_id` foreign key) through the form via `hidden_fields`.

Comment: Okay then as long as you already have the uuids in the controller (because you set it in the views), you can set  `@share_foo.foo_id = @foo.uuid` and `@share_foo.foo_user_id = current_user.uuid` right before the `@share_foo.save`